# Spring JSON cast class property to other class dynamically

Tags: json, spring, jackson

I have an (more) entity, which has a UserEntity class (creator).
Etc:

```
@Entity 
class TestEntity {

@ManyToOne
private UserEntity creator;


}
```

Now, on UserEntity i have a many field which not important to use it in some request.
And i created a class (UserEntityMiniFied with just important fields) which has a Constructor with UserEntity,

Well, can i solute this question dynamiccaly with one json annotation, i mean,
i try:

```
@JsonView(UserEntityMinified.class)
private UserEntity creator;
```

but it not working.

thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can say you're on the right track.

First – let's go through a simple example – **`serialize an object with @JsonView.`**

Here is our view:

```java
public interface JSONView {
    interface JSONBasicView {}
    interface JSONAdvancedView extends JSONBasicView {}
}
```

And the `UserEntity` entity:

```java
@Entity
class UserEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @JsonView(JSONView.JSONBasicView.class)
    private int id;

    @JsonView(JSONView.JSONBasicView.class)
    private String name;

    @JsonView(JSONView.JSONBasicView.class)
    private String age;

    @JsonView(JSONView.JSONAdvancedView.class)
    private String country;

    @JsonView(JSONView.JSONAdvancedView.class)
    private String city;

    public UserEntity() {
    }

    // getter/setter ..
}
```

And the `TestEntity` entity:

```java
@Entity
class TestEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @JsonView(JSONView.JSONBasicView.class)
    private int id;

    @JsonView(JSONView.JSONBasicView.class)
    private String name;

    @ManyToOne
    @JsonView(JSONView.JSONBasicView.class)
    private UserEntity userEntity;

    public TestEntity() {
    }

    // getter/setter ..
}
```

Now let's serialize a `TestEntity` instance using our view:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    UserEntity userEntity = new UserEntity();
    userEntity.setId(1);
    userEntity.setName("User Entity Name");
    userEntity.setAge("33");
    userEntity.setCountry("Country");
    userEntity.setCity("City");

    TestEntity testEntity = new TestEntity();
    testEntity.setId(1);
    testEntity.setName("Test Entity Name");
    testEntity.setOtherTestEntity(userEntity);

    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    mapper.disable(MapperFeature.DEFAULT_VIEW_INCLUSION);

    String basicView = mapper
            .writerWithView(JSONView.JSONBasicView.class)
            .writeValueAsString(testEntity);
    System.out.println(basicView);

    String advancedView = mapper
            .writerWithView(JSONView.JSONAdvancedView.class)
            .writeValueAsString(testEntity);
    System.out.println(advancedView);
}
```

The output of this code will be:

```
// JSONBasicView
{
  "id": 1,
  "name": "Test Entity Name",
  "userEntity": {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "User Entity Name",
    "age": "33"
  }
}

// JSONAdvancedView
{
  "id": 1,
  "name": "Test Entity Name",
  "userEntity": {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "User Entity Name",
    "age": "33",
    "country": "Country",
    "city": "City"
  }
}
```

You can also [check here](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-json-view-annotation) to do more.

Comment: thankyou! I need to add a property in my file, and it works, thanks

`code` spring.jackson.mapper.default_view_inclusion=true

Comment: Since I gave an example manual, I added it as `mapper.disable(MapperFeature.DEFAULT_VIEW_INCLUSION);`, if you want to set it as default with *Spring*, you can use what you say.